# IBM IIB: which encoding does it use for the system log?

Tags: character-encoding, event-viewer, ibm-integration-bus

I have installed the Russian version of IBM IIB. When errors occur, it spams the windows system log with unreadable messages like

```
 ôº½Ò »«Ô«¬á ß««íÚÑ¡¿® ¡Ñ Òñá½«ßý «Ô¬ÓÙÔý Ò¬áºá¡¡Ò¯ «þÑÓÑñý WebSphere MQ ß       ¬«ñá¼¿ ºáóÑÓÞÑ¡¿´ ¿ »Ó¿þ¿¡Ù WebSphere MQ Å«Ô«¬ ß««íÚÑ¡¿® »ÙÔáÑÔß´ «Ô¬ÓÙÔý «þÑÓÑñý ñ« Òß»ÑÞ¡«ú« «»ÓÑñÑ½Ñ¡¿´ «þÑÓÑñ¿.  Å«¬á ÝÔ« ¡Ñ ßñÑ½á¡«, »«Ô«¬ ß««íÚÑ¡¿® Óáí«ÔáÑÔ ¡Ñ »«½¡«ßÔý¯.
```

I think it is trying to write its errors in Russian but uses the wrong encoding. As a result, the event viewer cannot display the text correctly.
Which encoding does it use? I could not decipher it (tried several encodings)

Answer (score 0):

Integration Bus for Windows uses a system locale for messages in Event Log (see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ae19495_.htm)) so changing the system locale may help you. Try encoding 866